# How to implement async-await or then-catch correctly in a function with jquery request to google drive api

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, google-drive-api

I try to implement this async upload function and then when its finished, I search the file in google drive with another function, both functions work fine but the problem is that the aplication don't wait the upload function finish.
This is the code.

**Using the functions**

```
async save() {
      let dataRequest;
      await this.uploadFileGoogleDrive (this.files[0]);
      dataRequest= await this.listFilesGoogleDrive ("name='"+ this.file_Name +"'");
      dataRequest= dataRequest.files;
      console.log ("Data request= ", dataRequest);
      ....
```

**Upload Function**

```
async uploadFileGoogleDrive (archivo) {
  const file = archivo;
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsDataURL(file);

  let metadata = {
    'name': nombreArchivo,
    'parents':[this.folder_Id]
  };
  
  return fr.onload = function () {
    const boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    let data = "--" + boundary + "\n";
    data += "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\n\n";
    data += JSON.stringify(metadata) + "\n";
    data += "--" + boundary + "\n";
    data += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
    data += fr.result.split(",")[1] + "\n";
    data += "--" + boundary + "--";

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=" + boundary);
      },
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
      success: function (data) {
          console.log("Success= ", data);
      },
      error: function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      },
      async: true,
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      timeout: 60000
    });
  };  
},
```

I don't know why the wait don't work and I tried using await instead of return but give me this error "Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression".

**I'll appreciate any recommendation and thank you for your time.**

Answer (score 0):

In your function uploadFileGoogleDrive(archivo), change your code according to this:

```
return fr.onload = async function () {
    const boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    let data = "--" + boundary + "\n";
    ...

    await $.ajax({
        ...
    });
 };
```

This will wait for the ajax call to finish before further code execution.

You can read mor about async/await with ajax here:
https://petetasker.com/using-async-await-jquerys-ajax

Comment: Thaks but I already tried that and it didn't work

`return fr.onload = async function () {`
`await $.ajax({`